# ARKit and Vision frameworks for Object Recognition

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit, apple-vision

I would really like some guidance on combining Apple's new Vision API with ARKit in a way that enables object recognition. This would not need to track the moving object, just recognize it stable in 3d space for the AR experience to react accordingly.

I know this type of experience is available in services like `Vuforia` or `Wikitude`, but I would like to try it with only native Apple APIs.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to use Vision framework itself inside your project, because ARKit is already has this feature. All you need is to activate a [detectionObjects](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldtrackingconfiguration/2968177-detectionobjects) instance property that you can use right from iOS 12:

```
var detectionObjects: Set<ARReferenceObject> { get set }
```

Let's see what Apple documentation says about it:

> Use this property to choose known 3D objects for ARKit to find in the user's environment and present as ARObjectAnchor for use in your AR experience.

Here's a working code (as simple as that) :

```
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!
    let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        sceneView.delegate = self

        // add reference objects into Resources in your project
        guard let objects = ARReferenceObject.referenceObjects(inGroupNamed: "Resources", 
                                                                     bundle: nil) 
        else { 
            fatalError("No reference here!") 
            return
        }

        config.detectionObjects = objects
        sceneView.session.run(config)
    }
}
```

And, of course, insert an extension with renderer() method:

```
extension ViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate {

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer,
                 didAdd node: SCNNode,
                  for anchor: ARAnchor) {

        if let _ = anchor as? ARObjectAnchor {         // Special Type of anchor

            let sphereNode =  SCNNode(geometry: SCNSphere(radius: 0.05))
            sphereNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.green
            node.addChildNode(sphereNode)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm relatively new to this site, so I can't yet comment.

ARKit 1.5 in iOS 11.3 includes [Image Recognition](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/recognizing_images_in_an_ar_experience).

There is also support for running [Vision with ARKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/using_vision_in_real_time_with_arkit).

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking for, but these might help.

Comment: That "Using Vision with ARKit" sample isn't really specific to Xcode 9.3 / iOS 11.3 — most of what's in there can be done on shipping versions of Xcode/iOS.

Answer (score 0):

- To recognize (multiple) objects including their coordinates (to use in ARKit), you will need to train an *Object Detector* (not *Classifier*!)
- To have it exported into a CoreML model smoothly, the easiest ways to build/train it are CreateML and TuriCreate (slightly less easy).
- To add a 3D object to a particular spot in AR experience, you will need to find 'worldTransform' for its ARAnchor (that you will need to subclass).
- To find the 'worldTransform' you will need to fire a 'hitTest()' on ARFrame on the spot where the object was recognized in 2D.

Well, this is probably a good place to stop because your question is rather high-level.